# Thread in Android causes phone crash

Tags: android, multithreading, crash, deadlock

I have no idea what fails in this code because I have trouble reading the crash logs. We are not talking about a app-crash but a phone crash probably caused by either a deadlocked thread or a lock-up of some kind. Suggestions are welcomed!

---

#### Background:

When I initiate my connection a dialog shows and when I press the Back button the dialog freezes and after awhile the phone crashes...

#### Code:

This is the thread that handles the connection with the device. I have no issues connecting to a device at all. What I know is that `mmSocket.connect()` running when I press the back button. Think the problem lies there somewhere...

```
class ConnectThread extends Thread {

/**
 * 
 */
private Handler threadhandler;
private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
private volatile BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
private Message toMain;
//      private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

public ConnectThread(Handler threadhandler, BluetoothDevice device) {

    this.threadhandler = threadhandler;
    this.mmDevice = device;


    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
    try {
        Method m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
        mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, 1);

    }catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();
    try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
        // until it succeeds or throws an exception

        mmSocket.connect();

        toMain = threadhandler.obtainMessage();
        toMain.arg1 = 1;
        threadhandler.sendMessage(toMain);


    } catch (SecurityException e) {

        Log.e("SecurityExcep", "Oh noes" , e);
        toMain = threadhandler.obtainMessage();
        toMain.arg1 = 2;
        threadhandler.sendMessage(toMain);
        Log.w("MESSAGE", e.getMessage());

    }catch (IOException e) {
        //Bad connection, let's get the hell outta here
        try {
            Log.e("IOExcep", "Oh noes" , e);
            Log.w("MESSAGE", e.getMessage());

            mmSocket.close();
            toMain = threadhandler.obtainMessage();
            toMain.arg1 = 2;
            toMain.obj = e.getMessage();
            threadhandler.sendMessage(toMain);


            return;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.e("IOExcep2", "Oh noes" , e);
        }
    }
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("CONNECT_CONSTRUCTOR", "Unable to close the socket", e);
    }

    toMain = threadhandler.obtainMessage();
    toMain.arg1 = 3;
    threadhandler.sendMessage(toMain);

    Looper.loop();
    return;
    // Now it should be paired.. only thing to do now is let the user commit to the rest
}

/** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
public void cancel() {
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}

}
```

Next code is a snippet from the dialog creator, the thread is called `d`:

```
(...)

        case DIALOG_BT_ADDING:
        search_dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        search_dialog.setTitle(R.string.adding);
        search_dialog.setMessage(res.getText(R.string.bluetooth_add_accept));
        search_dialog.setIndeterminate(true);           
        search_dialog.setCancelable(true);
        search_dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Log.i("THREAD CONNECT", "Is it alive?: " + d.isAlive());
                if(d != null && d.isAlive()){
                    d.cancel();
                    //d = null;
                }
                if(d2 != null && d2.isAlive()){
                    d2.cancel(false);
                    //d2 = null;

                }
                search_dialog.dismiss();
                showDialog(DIALOG_NEW_DEVICE_FOUND);

            }
        });         
        return search_dialog;
(...)
```

Here is a snippet of the code executing the `ConnectThread`-class

```
private void connectBluetooth(boolean nextstage, IOException e1){
    if(!nextstage){
        showDialog(DIALOG_BT_ADDING);

        d = new ConnectThread(threadhandler, selected_car.getDevice());
        d.start();

    }
    else{
        if(e1 != null){

            d2 = new BluetoothCheckThread(checkthreadhandler,mBluetoothAdapter, 
                    5000, car_bt, after_bt);
            d2.start();
            search_dialog.dismiss();
        }
        else{
            showDialog(DIALOG_BT_ADDING_FAILED);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me!, thanks for any feedback

Comment: I don't think your code is doing what you think it is. Can you please explain what you _think_ it is doing? Why are you messing with Loopers in your thread? That run() call that you have is never going to complete until Looper.quit() is called. Where is this ConnectThread() started?

Comment: I think my code is pairing with a Bluetooth-unit. That's it's main and only purpose and it does that aswell. During the connection progress I want to send messages to a handler that works with the UI-thread which is currently implemented. Dialogs show when connections and such are timed out/host is down etc. But the problem occurs when I press the back button during a add-process.. could `Looper` be the issue?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why you're using a Looper at all here since you're not _sending_ the Thread with the Looper any messages. Its also unclear where/how ConnectThread() is started, are you calling run() or start()?

Comment: The `Loopers` are removed, but the issue is still there. It fails when `mmSocket.close()` is called during the `mmSocket.connect()` progress. Observe that mmSocket.connect() is a locked call.. that's the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you're calling `BluetoothSocket.close()` from what looks like the UI thread. This is probably causing the "freeze".

When you say the phone "crashes" do you mean it reboots? If so is this a full reboot (screen goes back to what happens when you first turn the phone on) or a runtime restart (phone typically shows some sort of animation, on Nexus devices, its the four-color particle spray)? If its not a reboot, do you mean you just get a dialog allowing you to kill the app?

In either case you may want to get a reference to the Thread that is calling `BluetoothSocket.connect()` and call `Thread.interrupt()`. I'm not sure if a BluetoothSocket is interruptible, but let's hope. Then after interrupting, call `close()`, which probably shouldn't be called on the main thread.

Comment: Nope I'm not.. calling cancel() and in cancel() I'm interrupting with `mmSocket.close()`.. UI freeze would not cause a phone to crash. The system would recognize that nothing is happening with the UI and the user is unable to do anything, resulting in a system dialog asking to "wait" or "force close"... this is something else :S

Comment: Indeed, I didn't realize `close()` on a BT socket would interrupt blocked calls. Can you describe the "crash" in more detail, perhaps along the lines I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `dialog.setOnKeyListener()` in that on keyCode_BACK cancel the thread. try this will work.

Comment: Isn't onCancelListener called when the dialog is canceled? By pressing the back-button i'm canceling the dialog right?

Comment: Canceling the dialog is the same as pressing the back key:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29

Comment: Stopping it when the dialog is running, thus calling `OnCancel()` in the dialog

Comment: instead of cancelling the thread try to use handler.removeCallBack(runnable);

Comment: Not launched by a handler, and why would I do the removeCallback?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're calling connect and close on BluetoothSocket which is a "no no". It seems to cause a deadlock. See this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14549) for more info.

Comment: Wow, so the question was tldr (too long, didn't read) but you posted an answer and that answer is based on assumptions you gathered while skimming over existing answers.... Welcome to the site but you're gonna get a lot of negative rep with answers like that.

Comment: don't just downvote. Try to read the OP's question and follow my link. I didn't post because I thought it wouldn't be usefull. I've experienced similar problems with the close function crashing my phone. I took the time to look up the link and post it. Maybe I was a bit sarcastic but if you read the question and example code you should understand why.